# website cloned in iframe (and javascript disabled)

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, iframe, prestashop

I have a big problem with my prestashop ecommerce, hired 2 developers to try figure out but none of them could help me.
My website is being mirrored by some hacked domains and all my content is iframed inside those domains.

They somehow disabled javascript in the cloned websites so my website is mirrored, but javascript is not working, that's why all the strings to disallow iframes in javascript are not working.

i also tried < meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny "> but thats not working either!

i don't know how they are doing that but i really need to get them to stop miirroring my website. it is probably some black hat seo technique or anyway something fraudolent

Comment: hey sorry to hear about your problem. I think this question would be better asked on [webmasters stackexchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) Doing a quick search they have [some questions that are similar](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78404/someone-has-cloned-my-wordpress-blog-how-do-i-prevent-it-from-hurting-seo) and some ways to prevent other people from scraping your site.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on an apache server ?
You should try to add this line to your .htaccess :

```
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
```

This will prevent your site from being embedded in an iframe on all modern browser. If you use iframe on your own site however, use this line instead :

```
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

This will alow iframes on your domain only.

Comment: Yes it's apache and mod_headers is enabled ... but sadly it is not having any effect either..